# Como testar meu aplicativo feito em Xamarin no emulador do Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-sdk

Fiz um aplicativo mobile android utilizando o Xamarin e o testei normalmente, fiz algumas modificações e quando fui compilar novamente, o emulador do visual studio permaneceu com a versão antiga, me impossibilitando de testar meu aplicativo. Com isso eu desinstalei meu aplicativo do emulador, porque achei que quando eu fosse compilar, ele iria voltar, mas não voltou. Agora já não tenho nem a versão antiga.

Isso é um bug? Como eu passo meu aplicativo para o emulador do visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, isso é um bug, eu estava utilizando a SDK do `Android Marshmallow 6.0` e resolvi instalando uma diferente (`Android Nougat 7.1`).

Para trocar é só seguir os passo:

1. No Visual Studio vá para > `Ferramentas > Android > Android SDK Manager`
2. Instale o SDK que você deseja.
3. Vá para > `Ferramentas > Android > Gerenciador de Emulador para Android`
4. Crie um novo ADB, com o SDK que você acabou de adicionar.

Pronto, agora para depurar o programa, use o ADB que você criou.